Brackets with self-sizing commands (`\left` and `\right` ) not highlighting in VScode
I was trying to change the setting of new version of Latex-Workshop extension on my PC stored with Win11 system. I failed, but I find that my brackets,if added with \left and \right,no longer highlights. See in the pictures.


I've restored my changes in the settings and files of extensions, but that didn't work. Without the highlights it could be hard to check whether my brackets appear in pairs, in particular when I need to use \left\{or\right.  and so on.
Here is what files I had changed:
C:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions\james-yu.latex-workshop-10.2.1\syntax\latex-language-configuration.json
C:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions\james-yu.latex-workshop-10.2.1\syntax\latex3-language-configuration.json
C:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions\james-yu.latex-workshop-10.2.1\syntax\src\latex-language-configuration.json
C:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions\james-yu.latex-workshop-10.2.1\syntax\src\latex3-language-configuration.json

and files of different version of the extension.
Here is what the contents of the files I have changed(an example):
{
    "comments": {
        "lineComment": "%"
    },
    "brackets": [
        ["{", "}"],
        ["[", "]"],
        ["(", ")"],
        ["[", ")"],
        ["(", "]"],
        ["\\{", "\\}"],
        \\["\\left(", "\\right)"],
        \\["\\left(", "\\right."],
        \\["\\left.", "\\right)"],
        \\["\\left[", "\\right]"],
        \\["\\left[", "\\right."],
        \\["\\left.", "\\right]"],
        \\["\\left\\{", "\\right\\}"],
        \\["\\left\\{", "\\right."],
        \\["\\left.", "\\right\\}"],
        \\["\\left<", "\\right>"],
        ["\\bigl(", "\\bigr)"],
        ["\\bigl[", "\\bigr]"],
        ["\\bigl\\{", "\\bigr\\}"],
        ["\\Bigl(", "\\Bigr)"],
        ["\\Bigl[", "\\Bigr]"],
        ["\\Bigl\\{", "\\Bigr\\}"],
        ["\\biggl(", "\\biggr)"],
        ["\\biggl[", "\\biggr]"],
        ["\\biggl\\{", "\\biggr\\}"],
        ["\\Biggl(", "\\Biggr)"],
        ["\\Biggl[", "\\Biggr]"],
        ["\\Biggl\\{", "\\Biggr\\}"],
        ["\\langle", "\\rangle"],
        ["\\lvert", "\\rvert"],
        ["\\lVert", "\\rVert"],
        ["\\left|", "\\right|"],
        ["\\left.", "\\right|"],
        ["\\left|", "\\right."],
        ["\\left\\vert", "\\right\\vert"],
        ["\\left\\|", "\\right\\|"],
        ["\\left\\Vert", "\\right\\Vert"],
        ["\\left\\langle", "\\right\\rangle"],
        ["\\left\\lvert", "\\right\\rvert"],
        ["\\left\\lVert", "\\right\\rVert"],
        ["\\bigl\\langle", "\\bigr\\rangle"],
        ["\\bigl|", "\\bigr|"],
        ["\\bigl\\vert", "\\bigr\\vert"],
        ["\\bigl\\lvert", "\\bigr\\rvert"],
        ["\\bigl\\|", "\\bigr\\|"],
        ["\\bigl\\lVert", "\\bigr\\rVert"],
        ["\\bigl\\Vert", "\\bigr\\Vert"],
        ["\\Bigl\\langle", "\\Bigr\\rangle"],
        ["\\Bigl|", "\\Bigr|"],
        ["\\Bigl\\lvert", "\\Bigr\\rvert"],
        ["\\Bigl\\vert", "\\Bigr\\vert"],
        ["\\Bigl\\|", "\\Bigr\\|"],
        ["\\Bigl\\lVert", "\\Bigr\\rVert"],
        ["\\Bigl\\Vert", "\\Bigr\\Vert"],
        ["\\biggl\\langle", "\\biggr\\rangle"],
        ["\\biggl|", "\\biggr|"],
        ["\\biggl\\lvert", "\\biggr\\rvert"],
        ["\\biggl\\vert", "\\biggr\\vert"],
        ["\\biggl\\|", "\\biggr\\|"],
        ["\\biggl\\lVert", "\\biggr\\rVert"],
        ["\\biggl\\Vert", "\\biggr\\Vert"],
        ["\\Biggl\\langle", "\\Biggr\\rangle"],
        ["\\Biggl|", "\\Biggr|"],
        ["\\Biggl\\lvert", "\\Biggr\\rvert"],
        ["\\Biggl\\vert", "\\Biggr\\vert"],
        ["\\Biggl\\|", "\\Biggr\\|"],
        ["\\Biggl\\lVert", "\\Biggr\\rVert"],
        ["\\Biggl\\Vert", "\\Biggr\\Vert"]
    ],
    "autoClosingPairs": [
        ["\\begin{", ""],
        \\["\\left(", ""],
        \\["\\left[", ""],
        \\["\\left{", ""],
        ["\\bigl(", ""],
        ["\\bigl[", ""],
        ["\\bigl{", ""],
        ["\\Bigl(", ""],
        ["\\Bigl[", ""],
        ["\\Bigl{", ""],
        ["\\biggl(", ""],
        ["\\biggl[", ""],
        ["\\biggl{", ""],
        ["\\Biggl(", ""],
        ["\\Biggl[", ""],
        ["\\Biggl{", ""],
        ["\\(", ""],
        ["\\[", ""],
        ["\\{", ""],
        ["@(", ""],
        ["@[", ""],
        ["@{", ""],
        ["{", "}"],
        ["[", "]"],
        ["(", ")"],
        ["`", "'"],
        ["$","$"],
        ["$$","$"]
    ],
    "surroundingPairs": [
        ["{", "}"],
        ["[", "]"],
        ["(", ")"],
        ["\"", "\""],
        ["'", "'"],
        ["`", "'"],
        ["$", "$"]
    ],
    "indentationRules": {
        "increaseIndentPattern": "\\\\begin{(?!document)([^}]*)}(?!.*\\\\end{\\1})",
        "decreaseIndentPattern": "^\\s*\\\\end{(?!document)"
    },
    "folding": {
        "markers": {
            "start": "^\\s*%?\\s*(region|\\\\begingroup)\\b",
            "end": "^\\s*%?\\s*(endregion|\\\\endgroup)\\b"
        }
    },
    "autoCloseBefore": ";:.,={}])>\\` \n\t$",
    "wordPattern": {
        "pattern": "(__)|(\\*\\*)|(\\.\\.\\.)|(\\p{Alphabetic}|\\p{Number}|\\p{Nonspacing_Mark}){1,}",
        "flags": "u"
    }
}

All the changes have been restored now, but that did not help.
And when I delete the extension by deleting the directorys (C:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions\james-yu.latex-workshop-10.2.1,for examples) and reinstalling the extension, it highlights for a moment until the focus has been switched to the codes.
So what I need to do to make it what it had been? I don't want to reinstall the software, for I do not want to rebuild the local environments--that would be a geart deal of work. But if this is the only way I can make it(rehighlight the brakets), I will do it.
Thanks a lot for your patience and help! I hope I have made my question clear.
